# Can you produce a hexagon socket on a turned part?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I want to design a turned part at the office and I wanted to give it a hexagon socket. I know that screws can have hexagon sockets, but I think it is due to them being produced in batch production. Is it also possible to create a hexagon socket on an individual turned part that is going to be produced by turning and milling (on a cnc lathe) and if so, how could it be done? Thanks in advance for an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool known as a [rotary broach](https://www.polygonsolutions.com/how-rotary-broaching-works/), specifically designed to be used in a lathe.

[image: rotary broach setup image]

Verbatim from linked site:

> Rotary Broaching, also known as Wobble Broaching, is unlike the
> conventional broaching method. The conventional method has a sequence
> of polygon or other forms that increase in size and are pushed through
> a hole until the desired form size is achieved. Rotary Broaching can
> achieve this in one pass by cutting the full form, one corner at a
> time, often eliminating the need for a secondary operation.

The retail price for this item is substantial, but there are [kits](http://www.hemingwaykits.com/acatalog/Compact_Rotary_Broach.html) on the market for a more reasonable cost. Stefan Gotteswinter has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2glVyU0_C0) series for building the components necessary to complete the tool.

The key aspect of this type of machining is the one degree angle referenced in the image above. This causes the cutting edges of the broach to wobble into the material being cut, rather than a direct press cut as is the method used in conventional broaching.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to not use a hex socket but instead begin not with round stock chucked in the lathe but *hexagonal stock*. You then turn the part while leaving a convenient length with hex flats intact and use those for rotating the resulting "bolt".

Comment: I believe the questions asks for a hex socket.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I know- I suggested a hex cap instead because it's easier.